# How to only allow Integers into a textbox

Tags: c#, regex

I have a voucher application, and when someone wants to create a campaign voucher, one of the fields they have to specify is "Target Audience". Sometimes the person might enter a string, or a variable that is not an int, and the server will just crash. I just want to implement an if statement to see if its NOT a int, and then do something. I have a regular expression, i just dont know how to implement it. Tried many things. (the textbox to validate is 'campaignAudience')

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(campaignAudience.Value, "[ ^ 0-9]");
```

Comment: Why use a regex? Use `if (campaignAudience.Value.Any(p => !Char.IsDigit(p))) {...}`. Or remove spaces from the character class: `[^0-9]`

Comment: Integers or numbers?

Comment: How about letting user enter anything and instead implement validation properly? You can display red border around control if entered value is not valid and refuse updating database when user try to confirm his invalid input.

Comment: `[^0-9]` is the same as `\D` see [Character Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_1) in MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have recently needed a similiar solution. Assuming you need an integer (number without decimal point).

```
public static bool IntegerAndIsANumber(this string val)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val) || val.Contains(',') || val.Contains('.'))
            return false;

        decimal decimalValue;
        if (!Decimal.TryParse(val, out decimalValue))
            return false;

        decimal fraction = decimalValue - (Int64)decimalValue;
        if (fraction == 0)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

It checks if given string is an *Integer* and if it is a number in the first place.

**Using:**

```
if(YourString.IntegerAndIsANumber()){
  //value is Integer
  }
  else{
  //incorrect value 
  }
```

P.S. Also have done `Unit testing` with this extension method.

Comment: Thanks @Carl my love.

Comment: @KeiFrancois Please check edited version. My original was different and by editing I left logical mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom TextBox that only accepts numbers, add the following to your project, compile then the custom TextBox will appear at the top of the toolbox when your form is shown in the IDE. Add the TextBox to the form and now the user can only enter digits.

```
using System;

using System.Windows.Forms;

public class numericTextbox : TextBox
{
    private const int WM_PASTE = 0x302;

    protected override void OnKeyPress(System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        string Value = this.Text;
        Value = Value.Remove(this.SelectionStart, this.SelectionLength);
        Value = Value.Insert(this.SelectionStart, e.KeyChar.ToString());
        e.Handled = Convert.ToBoolean(Value.LastIndexOf("-") > 0) || 
            !(char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) || 
              char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || 
            (e.KeyChar == '.' && !(this.Text.Contains(".")) || 
             e.KeyChar == '.' && this.SelectedText.Contains(".")) || 
            (e.KeyChar == '-' && this.SelectionStart == 0));

        base.OnKeyPress(e);

    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_PASTE)
        {
            string Value = this.Text;
            Value = Value.Remove(this.SelectionStart, this.SelectionLength);
            Value = Value.Insert(this.SelectionStart, Clipboard.GetText());
            decimal result = 0M;
            if (!(decimal.TryParse(Value, out result)))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Linq version:

```
if(campaignAudience.Value.All(x => Char.IsLetter(x)))
{
    // text input is OK
}
```

### Regex version:

```
if(new Regex("^[A-Za-z]*$").Match(campaignAudience.Value).Success)
{
    // text input is OK
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jules, you were a second too late. Carl already Answered.

Answer (score 0):

Limit the keypress event of the textbox to digits